# Curl to Python Request - Json

Tags: python, json, curl, python-requests

I would like to convert this Curl code into Python request.

```
curl -X POST https://KEY:SECRET@www.sendowl.com/api/v1/products.xml -F 
"product[name]=Test" -F "product[product_type]=digital" -F 
"product[price]=12.50" -F "product[attachment]=@/filepath.png"
```

this is what I have but I am getting an 500 Error

```
    from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1Session
    import requests
    from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1
    import json
    from oauthlib.oauth1 import SIGNATURE_TYPE_QUERY, SIGNATURE_TYPE_BODY
    from requests_toolbelt import MultipartEncoder

    url = 'https://KEY:SECRET@www.sendowl.com/api/v1/products' # Yes i did put Key and secret 
    headers = {"Accept": "application/json"}    
    payload = {'product[name]': 'test','product[product_type]': 'digital','product[price]': '23','product[attachment]': ('C:\Users\APPE\Desktop\SendOWL\\audi.jpg', open('C:\Users\APPE\Desktop\SendOWL\\audi.jpg', 'rb'),)}


    result = requests.post(url,headers=headers, params=payload)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- In `curl`, the `-F` or `--form` parameter is used to post multipart form data (files).  In `requests` you can post files with the `files` parameter.
- In `requests`, the `params` parameter is used for query string data. If you want to send your data in the body of the POST request, you should use the `data` parameter.
- For basic authentication you can just use the `auth` parameter.

So, your python code should look something like this,

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.sendowl.com/api/v1/products.xml' 
headers = {"Accept": "application/json"}   
auth = ('KEY', 'SECRET') 
data = {'product[name]':'test', 'product[product_type]':'digital', 'product[price]':'23'}
files = {'product[attachment]': open('C:\Users\APPE\Desktop\SendOWL\\audi.jpg', 'rb')}
r = requests.post(url, auth=auth, headers=headers, data=data, files=files)

print(r.text)
```

Comment: wow thank you for the explanation and example :) you are a lifesaver.

Comment: this might be a long shot but I am getting a 403 error and when the output pops up. I get a huge html file in the title its say are you human. Does that mean the auth is incorrect?

Comment: No, 403 means Forbidden, an authentication error would return 401. Try with a user-agent in `headers`, eg `headers = {"Accept": "application/json", "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:58.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0"}`

Comment: Also, i think you have the wrong url - it should be `/api/v1/products.xml`. I missed that before, updated the code

Comment: I figured it out. the last part needs r = requests.post(url, auth=auth, headers=headers, data=data, files=files).json(). Again thank you for your help. For a long time I was confused about cURL. lol